# ReadToken() is returning "Instance of 'Future<Object>'"

Tags: flutter, dart

**ReadToken() is returning "Instance of 'Future'"**

I was following this tutorial on the Flutter Docs: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files.

So, my problem is that, if I just run ReadToken() without running the create function then the ReadToken() function always returns "Instance of 'Future'". Note: I made some changes to the ReadToken() function, like the name. The function is below.

```
Future<Object> readToken() async {
try {
  final file = await _localFile;

  // Read the file
  final contents = await file.readAsString();

  return contents;
} catch (e) {
  // If encountering an error, return 0
  return 0;
}
  }
}
```

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong or anything that I should change?

Comment: you need to do `await readToken()` whenever you call this function in order to wait for the future to complete and return you the actual value `Object`

Comment: Thank you, that helped me figure it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: Yes. That clarified it a bit for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `await` `readToken()`. If you continue reading the documentation by the [complete example section](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files#complete-example), it shows this example:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.storage.readCounter().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _counter = value;
      });
    });
  }
```

It's using `.then()` instead of `await`, which `await` is a syntactic sugar for `.then()`

So, In your case it would be:

```
readToken().then((value) {
      // Do something with the `value`
    });
```

Comment: Actually, `await` is the syntactic sugar, `then()` has existed for decades and is complicated to use.

Comment: @nvoigt That's what I meant. Thanks. Edited to clarify